# ui-router resolve vs .run for security

Tags: angularjs, security, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I am curious as to what others are doing in regards to route security for their applications. At first we implemented our security by calling our security service from the .run method in angular

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, SecuirtyService){ 
SecurityService.initSecurity().then(function(data){}); }
```

SecurityService.initSecurity would then make a rest call to see what permissions the user has. The problem with this is that since .initSecurity returns a promise the rest of the application would execute until $http decided to execute the call therefor loading the UI without the security checks being finished.

So in order to combat this, in our ui-router i added a resolve to each of our states. This makes sure that our .initSecurity is fulfilled before the controller is loaded.

```
Header: {
          templateUrl: "header/headerBar.html",
          controller: "HeaderController as headerCtrl",
          resolve: {
            security: function(SecurityService){
              return SecurityService.initSecurity();
            }
          }
        },
```

The problem with this is that .initSecurity is called before each page loads which seems very redundant.

In a perfect world the .run method wouldn't finish until the promise has been fulfilled but https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4003 looks like that is not happening.

My question would be how are you implementing security checks on you application? Are you firing it off from the .run method somehow? Or is having it be apart of the resolve a valid choice?

Comment: We are using cookies, and verifing in the backend that,that user has access to the route. We are not checking on the client side, because no matter what you need to check at the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a parent state (we call it auth) and resolve security from there.

```
$stateProvider
 .state('auth', {
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
   security: function(SecurityService) {
     // Will resolve once if transferring between auth states
     return SecurityService.initSecurity(); 
   }
  }
 })
 .state('auth.profile', {
  ...
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deferIntercept` to pause the initial routing until your async check is complete.  Then use `listen` and `sync` to begin routing.

```
myapp.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
})

myapp.run(function (SecurityService, $urlRouter) {
  SecurityService.initSecurity()
  .then(function(data){
    $urlRouter.listen();
    $urlRouter.sync();
  });
});
```